# What is the Magazine Equivalent of ISBN?

Tags: book-collecting, library-and-information-science, magazines

I’m trying to catalog all my books and magazines so I can at a glance know what I have, and don’t have. I’m working on the magazines at the moment and noticed that they don’t have ISBN numbers. Do magazines have unique identifying numbers?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ISBN stands for [International Standard Book Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Book_Number). Similarly, **ISSN** stands for [International Standard Serial Number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Standard_Serial_Number).

The current standard for ISSN is [ISO 3297:2007: Information and documentation — International standard serial number (ISSN)](https://www.iso.org/standard/39601.html). The website [issn.org](https://www.issn.org/) allows publishers of magazines, journals and similar serial publications to request an ISSN.